# Trabalhar Seletores Dinâmicos (Ou Múltiplos Seletores) em Jquery

Tags: jquery, css-seletores, each

Tenho um código Javascript (Jquery) que pega caracteres de uma DIV e joga este resultado para uma outra DIV. Para a DIV onde pego os caracteres criei uma função que acrescenta uma classe dinamicamente, sendo nomep0, nomep1, nomep2 e assim por diante. Vejam:

```
$('.listagem .listagem-item .info-produto > a').each(function(i) {
            var $this = $(this); 
            var newClass = "nomep" + i++;
            $this.addClass(newClass);
        });

function firstnomep(){
        var str = $(".listagem .listagem-item .info-produto .nomep0").text();
        var res = str.slice(0,15);

        $('<div id="name-prod">'+res+'</div>').insertBefore(".listagem .listagem-item .info-produto .nomep0");}
```

Queria saber como é possível eu criar uma função em que este código funcione automaticamente para todas as DIV, já que a página pode ter mais de 50 DIV com a classe "nomep xx". No exemplo acima, funciona corretamente somente para a DIV com classe "nomep0".

Se eu não usar a classe "nomep xx" ele pega somente o primeiro seletor que encontra de ".listagem .listagem-item .info-produto" e insere os mesmos caracteres em todas as DIVs, o que não é o que desejo.

Comment: Quando é que a função `firstnomep` é chamada?

Comment: No fim de todo script com um  $(function(){firstnomep()});
Como disse, o código funciona...só tenho dúvida de como dinamizar

Comment: Não deu...eu acho que talvez seja algo com a função each...trabalhando cada caso em separado..

Comment: Mas eu não consegui entender a razão de criar várias classes com números em sequência. Faria mais sentido que todos os elementos tivessem a mesma classe. Se você está dando um nome de classe diferente para os elementos para identificá-los de forma separada, está indo pelo caminho errado.

Comment: Eu tô quase entendo a função dos códigos, mas acho que falta explicar de forma um pouco mais clara.

Comment: Geralmente a gente usa `ids` diferentes pra diferenciar um elemento do outro quando ambos tem propriedades diferentes. Elementos iguais, a gente usa a mesma `class`.

Comment: Então, criei as classes em sequencia, porque o seletor era o mesmo para todas as DIVS. No caso, a DIV se repete com o mesmo seletor mais de 50x na página. Eu pensei que se tivesse em cada uma destas 50DIVs uma classe diferente ficaria mais fácil fazer o código rodar, mas não consegui...

Quando criei o codigo sem as DIVs em sequencia, acontecia que o Javascript pegava todos os seletores da página.

Comment: Para entender melhor: A inserção dos caracteres, seria diferente em cada DIV. No caso consegui fazer o código, mas os caracteres do primeiro seletor que ele pega repete para todas inserções. Para ficar mais fácil entendimento, trata-se de loja virtual, no caso, são nomes de produtos..estes produtos têm nomes muito longos, então estou pegando a primeira e segunda palavra para jogando acima do nome e deixando o nome diminuído com "..."

Obrigado pelo auxílio dvd!

Comment: Não precisa dar um id ou uma classe diferente para cada div. Vc pode selecionar todas de N maneiras e alterar uma por uma.

Comment: Deu certo a resposta do Leite? Estava bolando um exemplo aqui mas se deu certo, blz.

Comment: Deu certo dvd e exatamente como vc falou..nao precisava de criar as classes...retirei as classes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque não fazes logo tudo no each que está a adicionar a class CSS?

```
var $this = $(this);
var str = $this.text();
var res = str.slice(0,15);

$('<div id="name-prod">'+res+'</div>').insertBefore($this);
```

Em vez de adicionares a class CSS

Comment: Nossa! Obrigado Leite! Fiquei a tarde toda tentando rodar isso! Deu certo! Obrigado!

Esta variável str está puxando caracteres com o slice, para eu pegar a palavra completa, no caso, a primeira e a segunda palavra, teria ideia como conseguiria?